# how to run composer.phar self-update in travis

Tags: php, composer-php, travis-ci

I am facing warning statements in my travis builds.

Warning: This development build of composer is over 30 days old. It is recommended to update it by running "/home/travis/.phpenv/versions/5.3.26/bin/composer.phar self-update" to get the latest version.

How do I then run this?

See an e.g. [here](https://travis-ci.org/simkimsia/UtilityLib/jobs/11184638)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inside your travis.yml

make sure you have this section

```
before_install:
  - php /home/travis/.phpenv/versions/5.3.26/bin/composer.phar self-update
```

in order to run the self-update properly

Answer (score 64):

It is not such a good idea to hard-code the php path as paths might change when Travis gets update. I suggest simply calling

```
composer self-update
```