# Laravel/Composer Installation Error

Tags: laravel-4, composer-php, phar

I am developed a simple laravel crud application past 2 months. now a trying to make another one. once go to the command prompt. its showing error such as

```
 Warning: This development build of composer is over 30 days old. It is recommended to update it by running "C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar self-update" to get the latest version.
```

now am in the path : e:\wamp\www\

then try to download & install  the composer from getcomposer.com.. but its showing error like below.

"Setup cannot continue because the following applications are using files that needs to be updated.

**Windows Explorer**

"

i dont opened  any windows explorer currently. then how this error evolved. please give me any solution. am restarted my machine 2 times.

Comment: You might wanna look at this conversation
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19064731/how-to-run-composer-phar-self-update-in-travis

Comment: Try running `C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar self-update` , it just wants to update composer

Comment: If you are using simple phar from composer, just download the fresh version from the getcomposer.org. If you are running composer globally you need to start your cmd with administrator rights and then run `composer self-update`

Answer (score 10):

This works to me:

1.- Open Task Manager and find Explorer proccess.

2.- Right click on it and kill proccess.

3.- Retry Installation and finish normally.

4.- Open Task Manager and at Execute new task: explorer.exe