# Error in Travis CI Build process for php application

Tags: php, github, travis-ci

I am trying to build a simple application but build process is giving an error.

Below are the contents of My travis.yml.

```
    language: php
    php:
    - "5.4"
    - "5.3"
    before_install:
    - php /home/travis/.phpenv/versions/5.4.25/bin/composer.phar     self-update
    before_script:
    - composer install
    script: phpunit --configuration phpunit.xml --coverage-text
```

The error which I got in travis build is below.

> php /home/travis/.phpenv/versions/5.4.25/bin/composer.phar self-update
>   Could not open input file:
>   /home/travis/.phpenv/versions/5.4.25/bin/composer.phar The command
>   "php /home/travis/.phpenv/versions/5.4.25/bin/composer.phar
>   self-update" failed and exited with 1 during...

You can also check travis repo url

https://travis-ci.org/anantwaykar/TheGuruCoder-PHPUnit-Tutorial/jobs/138116121

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20032743/223981

Answer (score 1):

Don't hardcode the path to composer as it will change, just call

```
before_install:
- composer self-update
```